# How to install Apache mod files?

Tags: apache, uwsgi, mod-proxy

This is probably a really simple question but anyways...

I am trying to set up a Django application server using Apache as a reverse proxy with `mod_proxy_uwsgi`. I've already got all my config files and uWSGI up and running. My problem is I am using the `ProxyPass uwsgi://` method but now the actual `mod_proxy_uwsgi` module isn't activated. When I tried to activate it, I noticed its .so file isn't there? (Running Apache 2.4.6 on Centos 7).

My question is, how doI go about getting the module going? Must I download the .so file? am I supposed to compile something? Apache's docs and google searches have been fairly unhelpfull on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so turns out I clean forgot to install `uWSGI` through YUM installer as well. Dosent help when you call the `ProxyPass uwsgi://` when there IS no uWSGI module installed.